# How to disable the try again password in ssh command

Tags: ssh, password, scp

I want the ssh command to only allow one chance in typing the password, if the password was wrong at the first time the ssh will return

```
Permission denied (publickey......).
```

Is there a flag that tells the ssh to request only once the password?

Instead of:

```
[nir@dhcppc4 ~]$ ssh pokemon@192.168.1.103
pokemon@192.168.1.103's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pokemon@192.168.1.103's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pokemon@192.168.1.103's password: 
Permission denied (publickey.....).
```

I want:

```
[nir@dhcppc4 ~]$ ssh pokemon@192.168.1.103
pokemon@192.168.1.103's password: 
Permission denied (publickey.....).
```

The solution must be on the client side (e.g. some flag to the ssh command or using pipeline), I can't touch `sshd_config`, or any other system config file. Because -in general- I build 3rd party software (so I can't generate keys nor config system files) that access the servers in the LAN, the passwords are saved in the DB (therefore doesn't need second attempt). And in my code if I'll be able to assume that I only have one attempt to `ssh`/`scp` it will simplify the relevant code.

Comment: As the answers show, you can modify this, but why do you want to? People make typing mistakse frequently, and the defaults are set to allow for such frailties. A better question might be "how do I lock out a user that has failed _n_ login attempts?" particularly if you are looking to protect against malicious logins.

Comment: My reason is complex and long. What I can say is that if the password was incorrect at the first time - it will continue to be incorrect the following times.

Comment: You want to do the most fundamental system administration function (authentication) but can't touch system configuration files? You're out of luck. If you care to explain your long and complex reason, perhaps we might be able to see the _X_ instead of the _Y_ that you've presented in your [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/145342)

Comment: I re-edit the question. I dont think the reason matters..

Comment: The only way I can see this even being an issue is if you're doing password auth non-interactively, in which case whatever utility you're using to do *that* should either have the facility to abort after one failed password or, if not, then *that utility* should be the subject of this question.

Comment: I also notice that ssh is noting a failed attempt at public key auth, have you considered copying your public key over and avoiding this entirely?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the sshd config man page `man 5 sshd_config`:

```
 MaxAuthTries
     Specifies the maximum number of authentication attempts permitted
     per connection.  Once the number of failures reaches half this
     value, additional failures are logged.  The default is 6.
```

So a setting of `MaxAuthTries 2` will be the setting you will need. `sshd` will need to be
restarted afterwards (has to be ran as root):

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

or

```
service ssh restart
```

On the client side this can set with ssh settings (look at `man 5 ssh_config` for the settings you can apply):

```
 NumberOfPasswordPrompts
         Specifies the number of password prompts before giving up.  The
         argument to this keyword must be an integer.  The default is 3.
```

So edit your `~/.ssh/config` file and add:

```
 Host <name_or_ip_of_host|*>
     NumberOfPasswordPrompts 1
```

Where `<name_or_ip_of_host|*>` the canonical IP or hostname you are using on the command line, or `*` for all host connection attempts. You can also specify this on the command line without having to edit your `/.ssh/config` file:

```
  ssh -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 user@hostname
```

Comment: Please see question edit. I wanted some flag/pipeline use and not changes in `sshd_config`

Comment: I've editing my answer giving the client side options.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MaxAuthTries in `sshd_config`. The default is 6, so keep in mind that you may be attempting pubkey auth before you attempt password auth when selecting your value.